# how to find all a hrefs that include current url with jQuery

Tags: jquery, location-href

I want to find all the href containing current url even if the whole href is longer. 
E.g.
Current url: `www.example.com/portfolio/`
a href url: `www.example.com/portfolio/#28`

What I want to do is to add class to all `<a>`'s containing current url path (even if they are longer). 
I used something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nav = $(location).attr('href');
if (nav) { 
jQuery('a[href$="' + nav + '"]').parent().addClass('current');
}
</script>
```

But the code add the class only to 's containg the exact same path like current url.

Comment: try http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/ or http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/ selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the starts with selector:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nav = $(location).attr('href');
if (nav) { 
jQuery('a[href^="' + nav + '"]').parent().addClass('current');
}
</script>
```